# Convergence of Sequences in a Topology Space

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be the real line with the topology $\tau$ in which the open sets are the sets of the form $\left(a,\infty\right)$, $a\in\mathbb{R}$. My question is, what should go in the " " to make the following true:

Say $\left(x_n\right)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is a sequence in $X$. We claim that $\left(x_n\right)$ converges in $\left(X,\tau\right)$ if and only if " ".

---

I know that constant sequence converge. Take $x_n:=(1,2,3,4,5,6,...)$. It appears that such a sequence converges to every value in $\Bbb R$. For instance, $0\in U\in \tau$, then $a<0<\infty$. Clearly, at some point $x_n>a$ and hence $x_n\in U$. I thought possibly the " " should be something about $x_n$ being increasing. However, taking $x_n:=1/n$, we see $(x_n)$ converges to $0$.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It may be easier to consider the sequences that are not convergent.

Comment: @DavidMitra: So, write instead: "We claim that $\left(x_n\right)$ does not converges in $\left(X,\tau\right)$ if and only if " " "? Nevertheless, I run into the same issue of classifying all such sequence. I can think of some; for example, $x_n:=(-1,-2,-3,-4,-5,...)$ does not converge in $X$.

Comment: And, what if the sequence is merely not bounded below? What if it is bounded below?

Comment: The sequence $\frac{1}{n}$ does not converge to any positive real. If a sequence $(x_n)$ converges to a point $x$, then for each $\epsilon>0$, the sequence is eventually in $(x-\epsilon,\infty)$. i.e. the sequence converges to $x$ if it is eventually $\geq x$.

Comment: @DavidMitra: I see. So, if it is bounded below it will converge, whereas if it is not bounded from below it will not converge?

Comment: Yes, that is right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $(x_n)_n$ is bounded below, say by $m$, then the sequence has at least $m$ as a limit: any open neighbourhood of $m$ is of the form $(a,\infty)$ where $a < m$. Bu then all $x_n$, which by definition obey $m \le x_n$ so that $x_n \in (a,\infty)$ for all $n$.

If the sequence converges to some $p\in \Bbb R$ then all but finitely many terms $x_n$ lie in $(p-1,\infty)$ so it follows easily that then the sequence is bounded below (it's easy to take care of the finitely many outliers).

So the condition is both necessary and sufficient.